# grid.ls only shows the top-level layout

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to use [`gridSVG::grid.garnish`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/gridSVG/versions/1.5-0/topics/grid.garnish) to add information to SVGs I export from ggplot2, but it only works on one grob at a time—that is to say, you need to know which grob is which. I understanding that [I can use `grid.ls` to identify the structure of grobs in a plot](https://www.stat.auckland.ac.nz/~paul/useR2015-grid/grid-slides.html), but when I call `grid.ls` myself, it only shows the top-level layout:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(gridSVG)

p1 = quickplot(1:5, (1:5)^2)
p1g = ggplotGrob(p1)
grid.ls(p1g)
# layout
```

I've tried using different arguments (like `recursive = TRUE` and `fullNames = TRUE`), and also a variety of different ggplot-based plots, but I invariably only get the top-level `layout` (or, with `fullNames = TRUE`, `gtable[layout]`). How can I see the child grobs?

I'm using ggplot2 v. 2.2.1.9000 and gridSVG v. 1.6-0 on macOS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`grid.force`](https://rdrr.io/r/grid/grid.force.html) ("*Some grobs only generate their content to draw at drawing time; this function replaces such grobs with their at-drawing-time content.*"):

```
grid.ls(grid.force(p1g))
```